# How to open modal behind ion-tabs [ IONIC 4 ]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, z-index

How can I show the modal behind the tabs?
Currently the modal overlaps everything even though the z-index is set to 2 and the z-index of the tabs is set to 5.

[How it currently is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTjU2.png)

[How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHinl.png)

I have been trying to use z-index, however it doesn't work on the modal. Here's the code:

***Modal creation***

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  showBackdrop: false,
  backdropDismiss: true,
  component: CreateExpenseComponent,
  cssClass: "createExpenseModal",
});
return await modal.present();
```

***Modal CSS (global.scss)***

```
.createExpenseModal {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  //--backdrop-opacity: 0 !important;
  .modal-wrapper.sc-ion-modal-ios,
  .modal-shadow.sc-ion-modal-ios {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35rem;
  }
 }
```

***Ion tabs css***

```
 ion-tabs {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
 }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Also wanted to know it after realizing that using a normal page with a normal routerLink is exactly what you wanted '^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are trying to achive with `z-index` is possible since the `ion-modal` element is appended outside of the current page. But there's a way you could work your way through it.

You can divide your background effect in 2 parts:

[image]

1. The first part is were your floating button is, i assume you have it along side the `ion-tab-button` in the tab bar. You can add a `background-color` with colors that matches the one on the modal, and create a type of **teardown** effect with pure css or the exact shape you are looking for. There's a ton of examples out there, you can learn more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/).
2. The second part is to position your modal right on top of the tab bar using `bottom` css property.

Comment: Hey that's actually a great idea! I've tried some solutions but it didn't work out. Your solution is probably the best way. Thank you for your time Ivan ! ;)

Comment: Tried it and it happens that you cannot click the button because the modal opens on the top half of the ion-fab-button. :(

Comment: Hmm ok. does it work clicking the lower part of the `ion-fab-button` ? If so, you can dismiss the modal clicking on the lower half of the modal under the `ion-fab-button`.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is for Ionic 6 but maybe it helps someone

You can use [Ionic's animation engine](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations#modals) to create a custom `enterAnimation` that will first move the ion-modal under what ever dom node is needed for your use case. There is a hook called `beforeAddWrite` that is specifically for performing DOM operations *before* the animation begins. The relevant piece of code would look something like this

```js
// rest of animation
.beforeAddWrite(() => {
    const modal = document.querySelector('ion-modal');
    const appTabs = document.querySelector('#bottomNav');
    appTabs.appendChild(modal);
  })
```

Comment: This is great, was struggling to find a good solution. Thanks!

Just to clarify, is `#bottomNav` your `<ion-tabs>` element?
Then you must be just overriding the z-index of the modal to appear below the `#bottomNav`?

Answer (score 0):

```
async showModalInsideIonTabs(): Promise<void> {
 const modal = await this.modalController.create({
   component: SomePage,
 });

 // render modal inside active tab page, so tab switch is possible 
 // with opened modal
 const activeTabPage = document.querySelector('ion-content').closest('.ion-page');
 activeTabPage.appendChild(modal);

 await modal.present();
}
```

ref: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/26792#issuecomment-1429319622